# How to convert pytorch (CNN+LSTM) model to tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, onnx

I am trying to convert CNN+LSTM model mentioned in the following blog [Image Captioning using Deep Learning (CNN and LSTM)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/solving-an-image-captioning-task-using-deep-learning/). Related github repo is : [Pytorch image captioning](https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/tree/master/tutorials/03-advanced/image_captioning)

I want to convert this pytorch model to tflite. It has both encoder and decoder checkpoints. As far as i understand both of them have to be converted to tflite (correct me if i am wrong)

**approach:**  using the example mentioned in onnx2keras library, [onnx2keras](https://pypi.org/project/onnx2keras/) i was able to convert encoder to tflite. but with decoder i am facing the following issue.

***Not sure what is the right approach. can anyone suggest better approach and help me achieve a tflite model***

> File “convert_pytorch_tf.py”, line 63, in change_ordering=False) File
> “/root/anaconda3/envs/pyt2tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch2keras/converter.py”,
> line 53, in pytorch_to_keras dummy_output = model(*args) File
> “/root/anaconda3/envs/pyt2tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py”,
> line 550, in call result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs) TypeError:
> forward() missing 2 required positional arguments: ‘captions’ and
> ‘lengths’

***Please let me know which approach to follow and help me fix the issue related to the approach i have taken***

Comment: Hi, Were you able to solve this? What approach you tried? It will be great if you can share more information. Thanks!